# Interior of closure of an open set

Tags: general-topology

The question is is the interior of closure of an open set equal the interior of the set?

That is, is this true:

$(\overline{E})^\circ=E^\circ$

($E$ open)

Thanks.

Comment: This would be true if $E$ was closed, though...

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Try $E=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, I claim there is an open set of measure (or total length, if you like) less than $\varepsilon$ whose closure is all of $\mathbb R$.

To see this, simply enumerate the rationals $\{r_n\}$ and then for each $n\in\mathbb N$ choose an open interval about $r_n$ of length $\varepsilon/2^n$.  The union of those intervals has the desired property.